# I cannot get ORDER BY to work (Date Type)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to ORDER BY a date type fields name is dDate (format example is `2008-12-26`) but it doesn't work can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

```
    $listsql = "SELECT contact.id, CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname) AS fullname, lastname, firstname,
                dDate, line1, line2, city, state, zip, phone1, phone2, country, whoAdded
                FROM ". TABLE_CONTACT ." AS contact
                LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_ADDRESS. " AS address ON contact.id=address.id AND contact.primaryAddType=address.type
                LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_EMAIL ." AS email ON contact.id=email.id AND contact.primaryAddType=email.type
                WHERE contact.hidden != 1
                ORDER BY email.dDate DESC";
```

It gives no error or anything it just does not line up the dates I would like it to have the dates line up DESC or ASC doesnt matter
for example:

```
2008-12-26
2008-12-27
2008-12-28
```

OR

```
2008-12-28
2008-12-27
2008-12-26
```

I get something like this

```
2012-11-16
2012-11-30
2012-11-26
2012-11-30
```

SQL OUTPUT IS:

```
mysql> show create table address_email;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table

                         |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------+
| address_email | CREATE TABLE `address_email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you so much for any help..

Comment: What doesn't work? What does it do that it shouldn't or doesn't it do that it should? Having no knowledge of your schema, the code above is correct.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It gives no error or anything it just does not line up the dates I would like it to have the dates line up DESC or ASC doesnt matter

Comment: Please add an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) example.

Comment: @compcobalt No, we know what you want it to look like.  What actual incorrect output does it produce?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry, I get something like this

2012-11-16,
2012-11-30,
2012-11-26,
2012-11-30

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE the_email_table` and the output as it would look in a console. Does it have faulty leading whitespace (if not a real DATE type)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added the SHOW CREATE TABLE in the question and I checked there is no whitespace anywhere, I also tried to ORDER BY email.id same problem... Can it be because I'm using two LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes it works like that

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it works like that, so the date format is correct and no whitespaces but how do I get it to work with the other query ?

Comment: @compcobalt No idea. It should work. You'll have to debug it by temporarily removing other columns and joins to find out what's going wrong, including the possibility that your PHP code is messing it up. Execute the query in a real MySQL client.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski understood, Thank you so much for taking your time and helping, I will close the question.

Comment: @compcobalt - Note that you are displaying contact.dDate, but sorting on email.dDate. It is likely that it is working as specified, just not as expected. Try either displaying email.dDate, or sorting on contact.dDate.

Comment: @RobertB I tried contact.dDate gives an error : Unknown column email.dDate and dDate alone don't give an error but don't sort

Comment: @compcobalt - thats the field from email, then. hard to tell without knowing your contact table structure. :)

Comment: @RobertB I wanted to say: it looks as if it's not including the dDate field in the SELECT because when I remove it the sorting looks the same

Comment: @RobertB also, it works when I ORDER by anything else in the contact like for example ORDER BY city or by phone2 and so on... but not anything from the email table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_EMAIL ." AS email ON contact.id=email.id AND contact.primaryAddType=email.type
```

to:

```
LEFT JOIN ". TABLE_EMAIL ." AS email ON contact.id=email.id
```

I guess never have two primaryAddType's when using two LEFT JOINs

So now all works Great!!!! THANKS EVERYONE!! :)